# In Android, is it possible to include a custom property in a style?

Tags: android

In my Android project I have a custom view with a custom property. Setting the property works fine:

```
<com.mycompany.CustomView
    [...]
    mycompany:myproperty="myvalue"
/>
```

What I want to do is set the property in a style, so that I have a style like this:

```
<style name="CustomViewStyle">
    <item name="mycompany:myproperty">myvalue</item>
</style>
```

And change the custom view declaration to this:

```
<com.mycompany.CustomView
    [...]
    style="@style/CustomViewStyle"
/>
```

However, this results in the build error `No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'mycompany:myproperty'`. Adding the namespace declaration `xmlns:mycompany="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"` to `style.xml` does not help. Is there a way to make this work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you should set your custom style like this

```
<style name="CustomViewStyle">
    <item name="myproperty">myvalue</item>
</style>
```

Comment: I have done this. As I wrote in my question, setting the style on the actual element works fine, it's when I try to set it in a style that I have a problem.

Comment: I am sorry that I misunderstood before. Updating my answer.

Comment: Perfect, that works! Don't know why I didn't try that.